# iOS @2x elongated images

Tags: image, ios, retina-display

I have a set of images with @2x for retina display detection. This works fine on most images, however 1 image is elongated. This image was added to an UIImageView in Interface Builder.

I know the names are the same (aside from the @2x part) and the files are both the same type (PNG). What else could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to manually set the frame of the UIImageView.

Comment: Wouldn't the frame have been set in IB?

Comment: I had the same issue with one of my projects, I solved it by manually setting up the image in code, rather than IB. I did connect everything using IB, but code was my way to go.

Comment: This worked for me. Building in code instead of IB. Very weird. Thanks for the help.