# iOS @2x applied to non-retina and not scaling correctly

Tags: ios, image, retina-display

I have *@2x version of every image I use in my app and as long as I test in simulator everything works fine. But for some reason on my iPod 4 (non-retina) app not only loads wrong images, but also scales them about 4 times their accual size. Answer given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442401/ios-2x-elongated-images) topic would help with scaling problem, but I still have to solve non-retina - retina issue.

Comment: Do you also have corresponding non-@2x images or do you only have @2x images?

Comment: iPod4 has retina display.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to have two files one for retina and other for non-retina display

ex: 
myImage@2x.png (bigger file for retina) 
myImage.png (smaller file for non-retina)

and then just call [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage"]

it should work
*make sure to clean everything, and try again.. hope that helps.

Comment: I had every image in those two versions, that was not the problem. But using  [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage"] to set them instead of using storyboard fixed everything. Big thanks.

Comment: if you use on the storyboard it will set only one image myImage@2x.png or myImage.png... so it has to be done in the code ;)

Answer (score 1):

you have to make background.png (320-480) for non-retina. and background@2x.png (640-960) for retina, if you want to develope for iphone5 too you have to make a background-568h@2x.png (640-1136) too

Comment: I did just that, didnt help. I have "@2x" and "568h@2x" version of background.png and default.png and "@2x" version of all other images.Is there something I'm missing

Comment: did you checked "Copy items into destination group's folder" ??? when you copied the images into your project ? and you added to targets?